# get data from a date range but by area

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get data from a range of date and where the area of the office is equal to `office->id area`. Here my query

```
SELECT * FROM office as d
      LEFT JOIN office_area as e ON e.ID_Area = d.ID_Area
      WHERE d.ID_Area = 1 OR d.ID_Area = 6
      AND d.date BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-09-30'
    ORDER BY d.date DESC
```

the problem is im getting data with date `2018-01-01` is that because the first where. How can I get just the data from the area `1` and `6` from that range of date

Comment: MySQL or Sql-server ?

Comment: You need to separate where conditions 

`WHERE ( d.ID_Area = 1 OR d.ID_Area = 6 )      AND
 (d.date BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-09-30')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need some parenthesis:

```
SELECT * FROM office as d
  LEFT JOIN office_area as e ON e.ID_Area = d.ID_Area
  WHERE (d.ID_Area = 1 OR d.ID_Area = 6)
  AND d.date BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-09-30'
ORDER BY d.date DESC
```

If you're fancy enough, you can even use [`IN ()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM office as d
  LEFT JOIN office_area as e ON e.ID_Area = d.ID_Area
  WHERE d.ID_Area IN (1, 6)
  AND d.date BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-09-30'
ORDER BY d.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

use `in` instead of `OR`

```
SELECT * FROM office as d
      LEFT JOIN office_area as e ON e.ID_Area = d.ID_Area
      WHERE d.ID_Area (1,6)
      AND d.date BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-09-30'
    ORDER BY d.date DESC
```

Or use parenthesis

```
SELECT * FROM office as d
  LEFT JOIN office_area as e ON e.ID_Area = d.ID_Area
  WHERE (d.ID_Area = 1 OR d.ID_Area = 6)
  AND d.date BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-09-30'
ORDER BY d.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some parentheses to get the logic sorted:

```
SELECT * FROM office as d
  LEFT JOIN office_area as e ON e.ID_Area = d.ID_Area
  WHERE (d.ID_Area = 1 OR d.ID_Area = 6)
  AND (d.date BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-09-30')
ORDER BY d.date DESC
```